# Python: function with list in arguments

Tags: python, function

I created a function which replace word by special characters in string.
It works well once I need to replace only one word.
Now I need to have possibility to extend list of words from one to more (2, 3 4...).

Working code for one argument - word you can find below.
What I need now is to have possibility to insert more than one word so it could be replaced in code by special signs.

```
def cenzura(text, word, sign="#"):
   if word in text:
       return text.replace(word, len(word)*sign)
   else:
       return text

cenzura("The day when I left", "day", sign="$")
```

Comment: If you want to pass a list as an argument you can do that just like with any other variable and treat is as a normal list in the code.

Comment: I tried and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy masking all words in the list with the same symbol:

```
def cenzura_list(text, word_list, sign="#"):
    for word in word_list:
        text = cenzura(text, word, sign)
    return text

cenzura_list("The day when I left", ["day", "I"], sign="$") # 'The $$$ when $ left'
```

To add: if you do need to mask different words with different symbols, you can use a `dict`.

```
def cenzura_dict(text, mapping_dict):
    for word in mapping_dict.keys():
        text = cenzura(text, word, mapping_dict[word])
    return text

cenzura_dict("The day when I left", {"day":"%", "I":"$"}) # 'The %%% when $ left'
```

Comment: NameError: name 'cenzura' is not defined

Comment: I'm just using the same `cenzura` function that you defined in your question :-)

Comment: Ok, now I got it. So we have two functions. One is mine and second is yours. So we cannot do the task within one function?

Comment: Sure you can. What you're after is method overloading, which isn't a great strength of python. But I can show you if you're interested.

Comment: @butterflyknife Instead of overloading you can also just check for type of variable with `isinstance()`

Comment: Ok, let stay with current way.